# Is it idiomatic to say "come out with me" to invite a friend

Tags: idiomatic-language

I see an example somewhere

> A: Can you **come out with me** for dinner at 7 in the evening? B: What about my English class that falls on the same time?

I guess guy A is trying to invite guy B to hang out.

My concern is the expression of "come out with ...".

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-out-with-something) only has the definition of "come out with something", not "come out with someone", and that means 'to say something unexpectedly or suddenly'.

So, is it idiomatic to say "come out with ..." in this case?

Comment: Are you familiar with the expression _go out with [someone]_? A is issuing the invitation so he says 'come out' instead.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you! So, the expression 'come out with me' is idiomatic, right?

Comment: Yes. "Go out with him/her" - "Come out with me".

Comment: @KateBunting  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come out with* is just a variant of *go out with* (because the speaker is issuing the invitation).

Cambridge defines *go out* as "to leave a room or building, especially in order to do something for entertainment" and, as an extension of this idea, to *go out with* someone often means to have a romantic/sexual relationship with them.

Comment: Thank you! But come out with me would not imply a romantic/sexual relationship, right?

Comment: Depending on who A and B  are, it could imply that B is being invited on a 'date'.

Comment: How about "come out with us"? When a group of college invite a new one.

Comment: _Colleagues_. You don't need me to tell you that that obviously isn't a romantic date!